# Normalize database (months by column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalize

I have a table connected to SQL(PERVASIVE) that outputs a column for each month.
For working it better in Excel, I need to transforme that 12 columns to only 2...
- a first one for the values;
- the second for the respective month (that at this moment, months are the column titles).

An example, turn the current database structure:

```
Al_Cta     | MoedCod | TpVal   | FlagDC  | Month01 | Month02 | Month03
AAAAA      |     100 |      20 |        5|      15 |      18 |      16
BBBBB      |     200 |      40 |       10|      20 |      21 |      26
CCCCC      |     300 |      60 |       15|      40 |      48 |      41
```

The desirable output:

```
Al_Cta     |  MoedCod|TpVal | FlagDC  | Value   | Month
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      15 |     01
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      18 |     02
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|       5 |      16 |     03
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      20 |     01
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      21 |     02
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      10 |      26 |     03
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      40 |     01
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      48 |     02
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      15 |      41 |     03
```

I already had some help in the forum, but I did not managed to do it.
I use the following command, but the database simply do not change at all, could someone see what is wrong?

---

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [IN16-CTAVAL]
Select p.Al_Cta ,MoedCod ,TpVal,FlagDC, 
       sale_quantity ,salemonths
  From products as p 
     inner join (    
         Select Al_Cta  ,sale_quantity ,salemonths from products
           UNPIVOT
      (
         salemonths for sale_quantity in (Month01 | Month02 | Month03) 
      )) as pp on p.Al_Cta = pp.Al_Cta
```

---

Best regards!!!

Comment: Are you trying to change the structure of this table, or are you trying to query the existing table to retrieve the data in the format shown?

Comment: Your UNPIVOT query seems correct, but it is just a query, so won't change anything as such. You probably want to change it to a SELECT * INTO [NewTableName] FROM etc..... Then you can query SELECT * FROM NewTableName to get the new format of data...

Comment: Thank you both

Bob Jarvis
I am trying to change the way SQL outputs the table, ie, I am trying that the "desirable output" is the only thing I see in Excel.

@Milney
So that I will have two tables in Excel, correct? The current one and a mew table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select al_cta,
moedcod,
tpval,
flagdc,b.*
 from maintable
 cross apply
( 
values
 (month01,'01') ,
 (month02,'02') ,
 (month03,'03')
  ) 
 b(value,month)
```

if you have more columns,you can add more in values clause..

The way above code works is

cross apply has access to rows of main table and you are converting them to  columns like below

```
values
(a,b),--row with two columns
(c,d)
```

so the above code will be evaluated for each row in main table and it will be a product of row in main table r1 and output of  values clause.some thing like below

```
Row1* value clause row1
Row1* value clause row2
Row1* value clause row3

and so  on
```

Comment: I did not down vote, but the same way you want them to comment you should also add some explanation to the answer. Chances are that is the reason for the down vote(s)

Comment: This is not dynamic so will only work for hard coded values... hardly a solution. This OP actually has an unpivot in his question which is the correct way to do this, he just states it doesn't 'change the database' so I presume he just wants to save this to a table... Your answer doesn't really answer the question so I also have downvoted it

Comment: I thank you for the time invested, but this will not give a dynamic and "allways ready" table, correct?